# Simple Android program not working

Tags: android

Hey Thanx for checking my question. im new to android programming. i have created a splash code but its not launching on emulator. it gives Application has stopped unexpectedly. please see to it. im using Android studio.

```
    package com.example.harshit.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Splash extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.us);

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    sound.start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent Menu = new Intent("com.example.harshit.myapplication.MENU");
                    startActivity(Menu);}
            }


        };
    t1.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sound.release();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: You should post your error log and a better description than "not working". But one issue, you're initializing the MediaPlayer with your context before onCreate is being called. Try moving the MediaPlayer initialization into the onCreate method.

Comment: @chris thank you so much chris!!!!! :D sorry im such a noob. but thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Did you include your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

2)
Here the correct code:

```
      public class splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer ourSound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSound=MediaPlayer.create(splash.this,R.raw.splashsound);
    SharedPreferences getprefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music =getprefs.getBoolean("splashmusic", true);
    if(music == true)
    ourSound.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
    try
    { sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {   Intent openMainActivity=new Intent("your package");
        startActivity(openMainActivity);
    }
    }
};
timer.start();

    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSound.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.us);
```

Hey you should place this line inside the oncreate function .You didnt provide logcat so the error will be due to this or you can check your android manifest. Weather you declare your splash class in android manifest or not. You have to declare all the classes in android manifest.